# SQL Server Migration Blocker unresolved reference to object [information_schema].[columns].[column_name]

Tags: sql, azure

Attempting to upgrade to azure via the data migration assistant and running into an issue regarding a reference to the system view, [information_schema].[columns]. This is a system view that is available in the database so I'm not sure why the migration tool is unable to resolve the reference?

> Computed Column: 'x' has an unresolved reference to object [information_schema].[columns].[column_name]. For more details, please see: Line 8, Column 27.

Comment: See [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9d854516-111e-44e3-8336-0cc71ff80b36/ssdt-database-project-error-sql71561-unresolved-reference-to-database-objectsreferences-to-other?forum=sqlservermigration). Also could you share the exact error description along with the error #

Comment: Is it typo in description you wrote `informationon_schema` but in title it is `information_schema` ?

Comment: Typo here, the correct view is referenced, information_schema.columns